# Why can't I see or interact with any heroes?

Tags: dota-2

I'm having trouble picking heroes in DotA 2.

1. I start finding a match - everything good so far
2. I find a match and everyone loads - no problems
3. Then a hero pick comes - problem

I cant see any of the heroes, so I can not pick any. I click random pick because that is the only solution that works, but again, the random hero is not shown.

In game I can see the hero, and I know it is mine, because it is the only one not moving. If I click on it, I do not see the heroes face, and I can not upgrade abilities, move or see items in the shop.

When I click on a player's hero, I can not see their items. When I click on an item spot, DotA 2 shuts down. I have also just gone into a bot match, and while it was loading, Dota 2 shut down.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Dota2? And do you also have this problem when playing against bots?

Comment: i havent but will i have to download all those upates again if i reinstall?  cuz i was installing them for 10 hours min.  yesterday :/

Comment: and i have just went into a bot match and while it was loading dota 2 shutted down.. i rlly dont know what is the problemm


and my friend told me that i should install graphichh drivers but he said that it is the problem MAYBE

Comment: What are your computer specs? this might happen if dota is not supported by your computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few steps you can try:

- Verify game cache. How? See [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335&l=english). See if it helps. If not, read on.
- Uninstall (delete local files) and download and install the game again.
- I did fast googling for the problem you described and looks like it's quite common. The solution I found is to reinstall whole Steam installation, **without** backing up games (at least not DotA, but preferably all). If DotA 2 is the only game you have installed on Steam you can **skip** first two steps and try with this one first.